# How to prevent a trailing comma while printing comma-delimited data in a loop?

Tags: php, loops, resultset, csv

I'm writing a php code which is supposed to echo some DB data as a group of arrays separated by commas.

The code looks like this:

```
include('inc_db.php');  
$query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE p_shop_id=1";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        if($result->num_rows == 1)
            echo "[" .$row['p_description'] ."," .$row['p_category'] ."," .$row['p_cost'] ."," .$row['p_stock'] ."]";
        else
            echo "[" .$row['p_description'] ."," .$row['p_category'] ."," .$row['p_cost'] ."," .$row['p_stock'] ."], ";
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

*the include line is the connection to the DB.

On this line:

```
if($result->num_rows == 1)
```

I'm trying to detect whether the loop got to the last row of the result, so the echo line would end without a comma (as happens on the 'else' phrase).

I guess I did the 'if' statement wrong, because when I'm running the program I'm getting the array with a comma at the end of every row including the last one.

the result is:

```
[Eggs, Food, 20, 20], [Coca Cola, Drinks, 5, 30],
```

The expected result is:

```
 [Eggs, Food, 20, 20], [Coca Cola, Drinks, 5, 30]
```

(without a comma at the end)

So what is the proper way to detect that the while loop got to the last row?

Comment: Do not invent the wheel and use __`json_encode`__

Comment: Create a variable $count before your while statement and set its value to $result->num_rows. This will store the number of rows you have. Now within the while loop at the end do $count = $count - 1; and in your if statement replace $result->num_rows == 1 with $count == 1

Comment: @u_mulder json_encode will also make the values in quote.

Comment: This looks like an XY Problem.  "**Why** do you need this formatted string to be formatted this way?" is the underlying question.

Comment: @ximewatch please do not post answers as comments. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230676/352329

Comment: @mickmackusa Got it. Thank you for your persistence.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to count the rows.  You don't need to know if you are processing the final row either.

I don't really understand why you need this format, but you can use `implode()` and wrap in square braces to concisely store row data.
Then when the loop is finished, you can just implode again with commas -- this ensures that there will be no mess to mop up.

This snippet converts the array of arrays to an array of brace-wrapped, comma-delimited strings, then after the loop, the array is converted to a comma-delimited string.  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qeqlB))

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT p_description, p_category, p_cost, p_stock FROM product WHERE p_shop_id = 1");
$rows = [];
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $rows[] = '[' . implode(', ', $row) . ']';
}
echo implode(', ', $rows);
```

Or you can prepend 0 or 1 comma before each braced string: ([Conditional Demo](https://3v4l.org/LTrX3)) ([Functional Demo](https://3v4l.org/6EFB9))

```
foreach ($result as $i => $row) {
    echo ($i ? ', ' : '') . '[' . implode(', ', $row) . ']';
    //echo str_repeat(', ', (bool)$i) . '[' . implode(', ', $row) . ']';
}
```

---

Or if you prefer functional iterators, you can omit the temporary variable `$rows` and just use `array_map()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AYaDn))

```
echo implode(', ', array_map(function($row) {
    return '[' . implode(', ', $row) . ']'; 
}, $result));
```

---

Or you could use `array_reduce()` and check if the there is any data written to the `$carry` variable as you iterate the rows.  The notion is to only prepend a comma if you are not dealing with the first iteration. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mopB3))

```
echo array_reduce($result, function($carry, $row) {
    $carry .= (!$carry ? '' : ', ') . '[' . implode(', ', $row) . ']'; 
    return $carry;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable which you'll increment in your loop and use it to check against `$result->num_rows` to see if it's the last record.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $index = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            if($result->num_rows == ($index+1)) //Check if it's the last record
                echo "[" .$row['p_description'] ."," .$row['p_category'] ."," .$row['p_cost'] ."," .$row['p_stock'] ."]";
            else
                echo "[" .$row['p_description'] ."," .$row['p_category'] ."," .$row['p_cost'] ."," .$row['p_stock'] ."], ";

          $index++;
            
        }
}
```